# Where can I ask this question about CS terminology?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a topic which is difficult to discuss effectively, because I lack the terminology I need to discuss it or even look it up on Google, so my specific question is

> What's the CS word which describes a type of computer system defined below?

I am happy to describe the specific question and believe it is hard to predetermine if it has a specific answer.
My question is about computing machine classification. I know of some classifications which include *"TTL"*, *"temporal logic"*, *"state machine"*, *"push-down automaton"* and *"Turing machine"*.

The question came up in a discussion about the multimedia environment [vvvv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vvvv). The documentation describes it as *"a programming environment"*, but I'm not sure it really is.

So as not to get into an argument about whether or not vvvv qualifies as a programming environment, or not, let's first define a computing-system of the type I seek a definition for, it's:

> **A computing system which maps a set of input-parameters to a set of output-parameters.**
>
> For example: In such a system as vvvv you can take a mouse X-coordinate as input and map it to a pitch control, or do that and also take the mouse Y-coordinate and map it to a volume control.

You can also have more complex input and output arrangements, for example taking a potentiometer input and mapping it to a texture scale coordinate so it scales along with the pot rotation, you could add a timer input and map it to the texture Z-rotation so it also rotates over time and you could take that same timer and pipe it into a sine-phase which you then map into the texture X and Y scale, the result of which would be a shape whose size can be changed by changing the potentiometer state and which rotates and pulsates as time progresses.

> In sum, the system takes in an arbitrary variety of real input states, usually from sensors, and maps them via an arbitrary variety of functions to arbitrary output end-states.
>
> Multiple inputs are mapped via arbitrary functions to multiple outputs.
>
> So my question is: To which sort of system classification or computing paradigm does such a thing belong?

Comment: It sounds a bit like an identification question and those have mixed receptions across the sites. Not all sites allow them, that is.

Comment: Did you consider [CS.se](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or [SE.se](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but I expect the latter to not be a good fit. It might help to narrow down candidates if you could have a look at these two and then [edit] why your question doesn't fit on those.

Comment: "What's the CS word which describes a type of computer system defined below?": Multimedia Toolbox. For something to read, to improve your question, see these pages: https://vvvv.org/propaganda https://meso.design/en/articles/the-flow-of-creative-expression-paving-the-way-for-vvvv  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vvvv/info

Comment: _"**A computing system which maps a set of input-parameters to a set of output-parameters.**"_ Every _computing system_ does this.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, yes but not many computer systems do nothing but that. The nearest definition I have is "function". It has greater scope than a state machine but less than a Turing machine. I feel sure it's something which probably should be identified by a unique piece of terminology even if it currently isn't.